# How can I host a reactJs/NextJs project on a laravel project's particular endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, web, next.js, hosting

I have a website built on laravel and another one built on NextJs.
I am hosting Laravel website on abc.com and I want to host the NextJs project on abc.com/new.
How can I do this?

Comment: it will be better if you do it on subdomain: ```new.abc.com```

Comment: You can use path based routing on most major webservers as long as you configure them properly. It's unclear what you are using here and what you have attempted.